# Get HTMLElement from Element

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an `Element`, and I can not figure out how to get the `HTMLElement` from it.

For example:

```
<a href="">A link</a>
<a href="">Another link</a>
```

I then get them like so:

```
var nodes: NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelectorAll('a'); // Returns a NodeList of Elements
for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes.item(i);
    // How can I get the HTMLElement here?
}
```

**Edit**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
let nodes: NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let i = 0; nodes[i]; i++) {
    let node = nodes[i];
    var c = nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: you need to use a type assertion https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You just need to cast it:

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let i = 0; nodes[i]; i++) {
    let node = nodes[i];
    var c = (nodes[i] as HTMLElement).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

You can even cast to a more specific element:

```
(nodes[i] as HTMLAnchorElement).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

The thing is that `document.querySelectorAll` returns the most generic element type, but if you know yourself what is the specific type then you can cast, because you "know better" than the compiler.

Comment: Might as well assert it when doing the query: `let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a') as NodeListOf<HTMLAnchorElement>;` or at least when doing the assignment: `let node = nodes[i] as HTMLAnchorElement;`

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that it would be more convenient

Comment: I followed this and got an error indicating that the Element was not an HTMLElement while attempting to call .focus() on it, so I think this may not work in all cases

Comment: @Alexandra This same code works great with `focus()` as well

Answer (score 16):

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('a');
// or
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLAnchorElement>('a');
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 6):

The way that works, is to cast the element to an `HTMLElement`.

```
let nodes: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll('a') as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
```

Comment: You've hit upon the problem: typecasting to a generic `Element` via typescript removes the ability to access `HTMLElement` attributes.  It's worth mention that in @Erik's `ES5` example, each node is implicitly an `HTMLElement` without typecasting.

Comment: @Cam It "removes the ability to access HTMLElement attributes"? Why would it do that?

Comment: @Nitzan A retraction is in order. What I should have said: without explicit typecasting, the compiler evidentially lacked sufficient information as to how to access the HTMLElement attributes.  Either casting each node to `HTMLElement` (as you have done) or transpiling to ES5 should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TypeScript, the solution would look something like this:

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

function isHTMLElement(node: Node): node is HTMLElement {
  return node instanceof HTMLElement;
}

const onlyHTMLNodes = Array.from(nodes).filter(isHTMLElement);
```

If you're only using JSDoc, it'll look like this:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

/**
 * @param {Element} node
 * @returns {node is HTMLElement}
 */
function isHTMLElement(node) {
  return node instanceof HTMLElement;
}

const onlyHTMLNodes = Array.from(nodes).filter(isHTMLElement);
```

In both cases, you'll end up with an array of HTMLElements.

`node instanceof HTMLElement` is the key thing that makes this work; if you manage to query something that isn't HTML like a SVG element, that will filter it out. The `node is HTMLElement` type predicate is what makes TS/JSDoc aware of what you've done.

The other answers here are okay, but either depend on implicit assignments that work just because you're querying an `a` element (so it returns `NodeListOf<HTMLAnchorElement>`) or use explicit type casting, which might be okay in this situation but, depending on the kind of query you're making, might stick you with a runtime error in the future.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone else is  using a combination of `jsdoc` and `@ts-check` for error checking

```
/** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLElement>} */
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a');

nodes.forEach( (node) => {
  node.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me

```
document.getElementById("elementId") as HTMLElement
```

Answer (score -1):

You're close!

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a'); // Returns a NodeList of Elements
for (let i = 0; nodes[i]; i++) {
    // node is your element!
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct, as I can not access `style` my editor says that it is still an `Element`

Comment: Yes, you can. With e.g. ´nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: I have updated my issue. please see edit. Also note that this is a `TypeScript` file.