# TypeScript - Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I got this issue working with TypeScript (for Angular2) when I try to get the id of an element.
See this example:

```
<div id="search">
    <div id="field1"></div>
    <div id="field2"></div>
</div>
```

If I try to get the id of one of the nested div, I can do this normally:

```
var element = document.getElementById("search");
var subelement = element.childNodes;
subelement[1].id;
```

Then I will have "field2".

However when I try to do this with TypeScript I got the message **Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Node'.** And as result my code doesn't work.
I really need a solution for this since I need to know the nested elements inside another, unless there are a better way.

Comment: Why don't you post the TypeScript code that didn't work as well

Comment: @DavidL is the same code, the only extra thing I used was a cast var element= <HTMLElement> document.getElementById("search"); but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: this is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234810/get-htmlelement-from-element/38235298#38235298

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nodes can be more than just elements and don't necessarily have an `id` property. You should use `.children` which is a collection of elements only.

Answer (score 1):

> ***error TS2551: Property 'setAttribute' does not exist on type 'Node'. Did you mean 'attributes'?***

`const elements = document.querySelectorAll("text");`

`elements[k].style.transform = '...........';`**////error**

`elements[k]['style'].transform = '..........';`**//is working**

`elements[k].parentNode.setAttribute('....');`**////error**

`elements[k].parentNode['setAttribute']('..');`**//is working**

Answer (score 0):

I would use document.getElementById to reference a DOM element in Angular2 but rather leverages `@ViewChild` like this:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div #search>
      <div id="field1"></div>
      <div id="field2"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('search') searchElement:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let domElement = searchElement.nativeElement;
    (...)
  }
}
```