# How to click a "DIV" element on a site, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to click the "continue" which is given on the end of [this](https://www.merckgroup.com/de/careers/job-search.html#query%3A%2Cpage%3A1%2Ccountry%3Aall%2Cstate%3Aall%2Ccity%3Aall%2CfunctionalArea%3Aall%2CcareerLevel%3Aall%2CemploymentType%3Aall) page, note that the site is not mine, its someone else's. The element is located after the pagination,

I tried to click it this way :

```js
//Method 1
document.querySelector(".se-pagination-button.se-pagination-button--next").click();

//Method 2
document.querySelector(".se-pagination-layout").lastElementChild.click();
```

But unfortunately it did not work for me. Is there anyway I can click it ? Because when you click it through the mouse or pad, it triggers a function. But not when I want to click it through the JavaScript.

Comment: Can you give more context than just a link?

Comment: That is not a button, nor a link, its a div.

Comment: @DavidRaluy: Yes, that's what he said.

Comment: @WEB_UI That's the link of the page, and the located "DIV" element. When you click it with pad, then it works but not with JS.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that site isn't mine, nor those answers fulfill what I need. I want to goto the next page of that site using JavaScript.

Comment: I think you need to read the post I linked.  It describes in detail what you need to do.  If you still can't figure it out, describe your efforts in a new question and ask about the specific problems you have with the code you wrote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I already defined what I needed !

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read that post and I concur, that is not the answer. I don't know why, but doing `document.querySelector(".se-pagination-button.se-pagination-button--next").click()` or `document.querySelector(".se-pagination-layout-right").click()` do not trigger the event the way clicking with a mouse does. I'd like to know why as well.

Comment: Post your code, include what you just said in your previous comment in the body of your question, and I'll reopen.

Comment: What code is there to post? That website is not his, and the snippets I posted are all you need to figure out that launching the click event on that div doesn't trigger anything, unlike clicking on the button.

I also installed http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2, and no event listener seems attached to the button, which is weird.

Comment: @Pete No it doesn't: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Yes @DavidRaluy you are right, how is it even working, Its weird

Comment: Changed it @RobertHarvey

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: hahaha I stand corrected @DavidRaluy, think I was thinking of querySelectorAll, but also if you look at the list of methods on the page provided, you will see that `Element` does not seem to have a click method, unlike `HTMLElement`

Comment: Added @RobertHarvey

Comment: @Pete then how that goes to the next page ?

Comment: Could try casting is as a html element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234810/get-htmlelement-from-element if you actually decided to post some html it would be really helpful - [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: It shows error on Casting @Pete

Comment: @NadeemAhmad Any luck on finding a solution? I'm stuck...

Comment: @DavidRaluy unfortunately no :(, I don't know how is it even happening !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website is a hot mess of different systems, but they use Vue.

So what you are looking for is:

`document.querySelector(".se-pagination-button.se-pagination-button--next").__vue__._events.tap[0]()`